# Which fuse to use SL or TL?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

Have a bad fuze of 30 am.
When I went to lows I have to options SL or TL. I don’t know what fuze to use.

This old fuse box in my garage.
And has fuse( green one) got bad.

Edited-
I have added breaker panel pic which 40 amp breaker for garage.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: What do the fuse protect?  30 amps are usually used for dryers/high power devices, not for outlets/lights.  Was a bad idea in the fuse age to increase the fuse size to prevent popping/burning up fuses when the problem is somewhere else.  Fuses/circuit breakers prevent the house/building from burning down from electrical problems.

Comment: The existing one was 30 am so I am just replacing the bad one with the new one . But I don’t know SL or TL .

Comment: I do not know the difference, but think it has to do with tripping time.  Too big a size is bad, so knowing what is on that circuit is more important.  A dryer is okay, household outlets/lights is bad/much too big.  Should be 15 or 20, fuse age more like 15.  Do not repeat a bad mistake from the past.  search found this  https://www.thespruce.com/home-fuse-box-how-they-work-1824667

Comment: What does "in my garage door" mean?   Is this the fuse for your garage door motor?  If not, what matters most is what is powered by it.  What things are on this circuit?

Comment: Sorry , it’s in garage. I updated

Comment: I see another one is yellow W type.

Comment: What is this fuse for?  What does it feed?

Comment: @jay613 - each fuse connect to one GFC  outlet and other 2 non regular outlets. Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

A little Googling finds that the difference between the TL and SL fuses is the base. The TL fits a standard Edison base so that any size fuse can be used. The SL base is designed so that different amperage fuses cannot be used in the same socket which is for safety (the threads on each size fuse are different). An SL fuse will fit an Edison socket when used with an adapter.

Comment: Thanks I am going to try this. I'll accept the answer if it resolve my issue

Comment: I have added a pic of breaker panel showing its driving 40 am breaker for garage.

Answer (score 1):

15 and 20 amp outlets (GFCI or not, as noted in your comment above) should be protected by 15 or 20 amp breakers (or fuses) depending on the wiring connecting them.  You should replace these 30A fuses with 15A or 20A ones.    Whether SL or TL should be easy to decide: They are visiby different.  Look at the fuses in your two package pictures, remove one of your existing ones and compare it. It should be obvious which one you need.  But don't replace it with 30A.